# Regularly plugging in SSDs to increase data lifetime

Tags: ssd, usb-flash-drive

I am aware that SSDs and flash drives lose data while unplugged.  How much does plugging them in regularly (monthly or weekly) increase data lifetime?

Comment: That is nonsense. Please search the web first before you ask. http://ssd-life.com/eng/how.html

Comment: The article talks about how many times one can write to an SSD before it is worn out, which is totally different from what I'm talking about.  By searching the web, I read that SSD cells discharge and they lose data while stored without power.  I was wondering if powering them regularly helps.

Comment: I think that is just superstition. In an average room temperature (25 Celsius or 77 Fahrenheit), depending on the quality of the SSD, it should be fine for 6 months to 1 year. Yes if you power them, the counter resets.

Comment: Thanks, how long can I expect data on SSD to last if I regularly "reset the counter"?